# How to program a dropdown option to load a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, json, material-design, dropdown

I am attempting to develop a javascript web application. In this application, I need a drop-down list of various commercial industries (options: Healthcare, Banking, Education etc.). When a user selects an option and clicks the "next" button the application needs to load a JSON file specific to the option chosen (Healthcare.json, Banking.json, Education.json etc.).

My question is: How do I link each option from the dropdown list to a specific JSON file? So that the JSON file is loaded when the "next" button is clicked.

I have a working list and button (for me that is an achievement) but can't figure out how to link a JSON and load it.

Sub-question:
Where do I store these industy specific json files? Just in the same folder as my javascript code?

This is my first application so any help is greatly appreciated!

I have searched SOF and google and have come up empty-handed. I have only found "how to populate a list with json data" and "how to build a dynamic list from a json array" neither of which are what I am looking for.

I expect the working solution to simply load the JSON file associated with each industry once the "next" button is clicked.

Thanks in advance

**THIS IS MY CODE:**

THIS IS MY LIST:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Industry" [(ngModel)]="industry">
        <mat-option [value]="1">None</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="2">Healthcare</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="3">Banking</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="4">Education</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let vm of viewModelsService.viewModels" [value]=vm>
            {{vm.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

THIS IS MY BUTTON:

```html
<button mat-button [disabled]="getScoreExpressionError()" (click)="loadJSON(); showScoreVariables = false">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to load the JSON data dynamically.
You can simple define the JSON data in the single Javascript or Typescript file static and import that file directly inside your Javascript file.
I'm assuming that you are using Angular and here is my example.

> static-data.ts

```
export const data = {
   healthCare: {
      ...
   },
   banking: {
      ...
   },
   education: {
      ...
   }
}
```

Then in your component ts file, import this data.

```
...
import { data } from 'static-data';
...
```

Now you can use this data in your "next" button handler that might be defined in the component ts file.

> e.g. with your example code, you can use this 'data' variable inside your 'loadJSON' function.

I'm sure that you know how to get selected data from material dropdown.
I hope this article definitely helps you.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! could you please elaborate on how the 'loadJSON' function should look/function? I can't figure out how to only load one specific object from the static-data.ts list.

For example, if a user clicks on 'banking' in the dropdown list and clicks next, I want to only load the banking JSON object ( banking: {...} ).